# How to let a thread wait until task is finished?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was trying to write some linear algebra library in java and wanted to implement multithreading, using the CPU. For this, I've created a class `ComputationMaster` that has 8 `ComputationThread`'s.

The idea is that when as task is given to the Master, it will give this task to all of the Threads and they will work on that.

My attempt was the following:

A task is a method that is called until it returns `false`. 
The method itself needs to manage on what data it is working but this is not part of the question itself.

```
public interface ComputationMethod {
    public boolean execute();
}
```

Now, let's talk about the ComputationThread:
It extends `Thread` and looks like this:

```
ComputationMethod computation;

public ComputationThread(){
    super();
    this.start();
}

public void run(){
    while(!this.isInterrupted()){
        try{
            if(computation != null){
                while(computation.execute()){}
                computation = null;
                ComputationMaster.notify_thread_finished();
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.interrupt();
        }
    }
    this.interrupt();
}
```

You can see that it notifies the ComputationMaster that he finished the task because the task itself returned `false`.

Finally, I will show you my attempt for my `ComputationMaster`:

```
public static final int MAX_THREAD_AMOUNT = 8;
public static Thread MAIN_THREAD;
private static ComputationThread[] threads = new ComputationThread[MAX_THREAD_AMOUNT];


static int finished = 0;
static synchronized void notify_thread_finished(){
    finished ++;
    if(finished == MAX_THREAD_AMOUNT){
        MAIN_THREAD.notifyAll();
        finished = 0;
    }
}
public static void compute(ComputationMethod method){
    for(ComputationThread t:threads){
        t.computation = method;
    }

    MAIN_THREAD = Thread.currentThread();
    try {
        MAIN_THREAD.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The idea is that when the `ComputationMaster`get's a method to calculate, it will give it to all the threads and wait until they are finished. 
I have not worked with waiting Threads yet so I tried saving the current Thread and let it continue, once the counter of finished Threads is equal to the amount of total threads.

This seemed pretty logical for me but there are multiple issues with my code:

1. An `IllegalMonitorStateException` is thrown.
2. Assuming that the task has finished, the `ComputationThreads` will go into an infinite loop and wait until a new task is given. (Perhaps this could also be done with letting them wait)

I do not want to create a new thread every time a new task is given and destroy them once the task is finished.

Comment: Why not use an executor service instead of trying to invent one on your own? You should note that a thread can only run once. If you don't design it - as executor's threads are designed - to run tasks from a queue in a loop - then once they have finished their task, they can't be reused.

Comment: Are you familar with [Thread.join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join())? That's the standard way to wait for a thread to complete.  Far easier that doing all that signaling between worker thread and master thread.

Comment: Yeah I know that. I mean, I've got a loop and I kinda got a queue. I just want to let them wait until new data exists. This is what the question is about.

Comment: @selbie This would require my threads to interrupt, wouldn't it? I am familiar with join but I do not want to interrupt my threads because creating a new one would cost to much time later when I need to do many computations.

Comment: Given that you are spinning each thread and burning a core while `computation` method is `null`, the cost of spinning up a thread is trivial to the savings you get from fixing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need all that signaling between threads. You can just use thread.join

Also, one minor design flaw is that you have the threads in an infinite spin loop until the `computation` member is set.  This will slow your initial performance a bit.  You should set the `computation` member BEFORE starting the thread.  That is, don't let the constructor of `ComputationThread` invoke `thread.start`.  Do that in your `compute` function.

This is likely what you seek:

```
public static void compute(ComputationMethod method){
    for(ComputationThread t:threads){
        t.computation = method;
        t.start();
    }

    // wait for all threads to finish
    for(ComputationThread t:threads){
        t.join();
    }
}
```

Then your run function is simplified to:

```
public void run(){

   try {
       while(computation.execute()){}
   }
   catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Comment: But doesn't this require me to create a new thread every time a new task is submitted?
How much does it cost to create a new thread? Is it quick?

Comment: Probably an easy trade off from burning a full core for each thread while the `computation` member is null.

Comment: I can tell you what I am using this for. I've implemented a neural network library and a new task would be calculating the output of 1 neuron (which is roughly 2000 computations) (depends on the neuron)

One full network computation would then be like 10000 new threads. 
Should i code it so that a thread can do multiple neurons?

Comment: You basically want a thread pool.  Look at the executor service thing RealSkeptic is suggesting.  Google for "java thread pools".  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/pools.html

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping that I did not have to use some preprogrammed stuff but fine :)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you can use package `java.util.concurrent` to achieve your goal. First you want to build an `ExecutorService`:

```
ExecutorService svc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
```

Here, I'm using one that relies on a fixed number of threads to execute tasks; the basic method to submit a task to it is `execute()`:

```
svc.execute(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello!");
    }
});
```

However, this has the limitation that the called method has no return value, whereas instead you need to return a `Boolean`. To do that, call `submit()`:

```
Future<Boolean> submit = svc.submit(new Callable<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public Boolean call() {
        return true;
    }
});
```

The above code can be simplified using a [lambda expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html), introduced with Java 8:

```
Future<Boolean> submit = svc.submit(() -> true);
```

This is a wrap-up:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Threads {
    private final ExecutorService svc;

    public Threads(ExecutorService svc) {
        this.svc = svc;
    }

    public List<Future<Boolean>> execute(List<ComputationMethod> methods) throws InterruptedException {
        return svc.invokeAll(methods.stream()
                .map(im -> (Callable<Boolean>) im::execute)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));
    }
}
```

A few notes here:

- I'm using `invokeAll()` instead of `submit()` because I needed to process a list of computations, not only one
- I transformed the list of `ComputationMethod` into a list of `Callable` using [Streaming APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) introduced in Java 8
- I avoided creating an anonymous class for every `Callable` and used a lambda expression instead

This is an example of how you can use the above class:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

public class ThreadsTest {
    @Test
    public void runThreeCalculations() throws InterruptedException {
        ExecutorService svc = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        Threads threads = new Threads(svc);
        List<Future<Boolean>> executions = threads.execute(Arrays.asList(
                () -> true,
                () -> true,
                () -> true
        ));
        svc.shutdown();
        svc.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        List<Boolean> results = executions.stream().map(
                f -> {
                    try {
                        return f.get();
                    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                        throw new AssertionError(e);
                    }
                }
        ).collect(Collectors.toList());

        assertEquals(Arrays.asList(true, true, true), results);
    }
}
```

In this self-contained example, which uses the [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit4/) testing framework, I'm shutting down the `Executor` after I used it and I wait for it to shut down:

```
svc.shutdown();
svc.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

However, in production cases, you might want to keep the executor around to be able to keep processing tasks.

On the use of `Future`, which alone deserves a whole post, here's what you need to know to get started: it represents a computation that might end in the future, and you have a way to try and extract the computed value out of it.

In the above example, I use `get()` to do that, but only because I'm sure the task has ended (since I shut down the executor, and waited 10 seconds in case of problems / hangs), but in general you can also

- check whether a `Future` has completed via method `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`
- `cancel()` it
- check whether the task is done or canceled via `isDone()` and `isCancelled()`

Hope this helps!